# Count points in a HTML test

Tags: javascript, html

I've got quite a few HTMLs, which make up a test. I need to count the points in all those files (whether the student has answered correctly or not), and in the final HTML pick a mark from a range of correct answers. There are 16 questions, and the last question uses matchimages.js library, meaning a student can get 7 points, depending on the number of correctly matched pictures. Found the library here: https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/QuizImage/match/

Comment: I do not understand what your question is about? 
Do you want to know how to do the problem that you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have several HTML-pages, each one with a form on it. Students fill these forms, and you want to evaluate the answers each student gave. Right?

This can not be answered in a single post. You have to learn about form filling, validating and evaluating. You will need at least HTML and some PHP.

And the js-library you use is a totally different thing … I suggest you start with handling forms with HTML/PHP. You can find a very basic example on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp